# C# htmlAgility Webscrape html node inside the first Html node

Tags: c#, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am trying to access these nodes 
on this website.
http://bcres.paragonrels.com/publink/default.aspx?GUID=2033c143-cdf1-46b4-9aac-2e27371de22d&Report=Yes

however they appear to be in a secondary Html document within the initial one.
I am confused how I access the secondary html path and then parse through for the

this is an example of one of the nodes.

```
<div style="top:219px;left:555px;width:45px;height:14px;" id="" class="mls29">2</div>
```

I am using htmlAgility pack and I recieve null whenever I try to access Div.
I tried working my way down the nodes but It didn't work.

Any help or a place to look up the necessary information to figure this out would be appreciated

```
var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
var document =    webGet.Load("http://bcres.paragonrels.com/publink/default.aspx?GUID=d27a1d95- 623d-4f6a-9e49-e2e46ede136c&Report=Yes");
var divTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html");
var text = document.DocumentNode.InnerText;
MessageBox.Show(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to scrape the data if you access the following url:

http://bcres.paragonrels.com/publink/Report.aspx?outputtype=HTML&GUID=2033c143-cdf1-46b4-9aac-2e27371de22d&ListingID=262103824:0&Report=Yes&view=29&layout_id=63

```
HtmlWeb w = new HtmlWeb();
var hd = w.Load("http://bcres.paragonrels.com/publink/Report.aspx?outputtype=HTML&GUID=2033c143-cdf1-46b4-9aac-2e27371de22d&ListingID=262103824:0&Report=Yes&view=29&layout_id=63");
var presentedBy = hd.DocumentNode.CssSelect(".mls23.at-phone-link");
if (presentedBy != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(presentedBy.FirstOrDefault().InnerText);
}
```

As an example, scraping the Presented By field:

[image]

Remarks:

1. I use ScrapySharp nuget package along with HtmlAgilityPack, so I can scrape using css selectors instead of xpath expressions - something I find easier to do.
2. The url you are scraping from is your problem. I am scraping from the last get request that is performed after the page is loaded, as you can see in the screenshot below, using Firefox developer tools to analyze the site traffic/network requests/responses:

[image]

I could not yet identify who/what triggers this http request in the end (may be by javascript code, may be via one of the frame htmls that are requested in the main document (the frame-enabled one).

If you only have a couple of urls like this to scrape, then even manually extracting the correct url will be an option.